# Modal popup not working for dynamically generated list items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a modal whenever a user selects on the X image inside of a LI item inside of a UL. The items are dynamically generated from items that are inside of the TempData field. I can assign the data-target to a static field and it will work without any issues, but no luck for the generated ones. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("ShiftSegments"))
{
var NewShiftSegments =
    new List<ShiftSegmentData>();
NewShiftSegments =
    (List<ShiftSegmentData>)TempData["ShiftSegments"];
if (NewShiftSegments != null)
{
    foreach (var item in NewShiftSegments)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item segment" id="segment">
            <span class="glyphicon">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" 
                   data-target="#shiftSegmentDeleteModal">
                    <img src="~/img/close.png" />
                </a>
            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div href="#" class="col-md-4">
                @item.ShiftSegmentTypeName
            </div>
            <div href="#" class="badge col-md-6">
                @item.StartDT.TimeOfDay
                -
                @item.EndDT.TimeOfDay
            </div>
        </li>
    }
}
}
```

And here is the modal I am trying to open:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="shiftSegmentDeleteModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Down Time?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to delete this Down Time period?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnConfirmSegmentDelete">Confirm</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cancelSegmentDelete" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

give class to your href link class="mypopup"

$(document).on('click', '.mypopup', function(e) { $('#shiftSegmentDeleteModal').modal('show'); });

Comment: The event still doesn't fire.